# Running save() for all objects

Tags: python, django

I will be making a migration on my website today and I added new field(slug) and slugify method with save(). It goes like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.tag+'-'+self.title)
        super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

My model has about 50 entries and I don't want to be saving them all manually just to generate slug for all of them.

Is there a way to do it automatically?

Comment: Why not just `for img in Image.objects.all(): img.save()`?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/migrations/#data-migrations

Comment: Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by just running a simple migrate command.

First you need to generate an empty migration for your app.

> python manage.py makemigrations --empty yourappname

The generated migration file will look something like this:

```
# Generated by Django A.B on YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
from django.db import migrations

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('yourappname', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
    ]
```

In the operations list you can append your raw SQL queries.

> operations = [
>       migrations.RunSQL('SQL query to alter your slug field'), 
>   ]

For eg:

```
migrations.RunSQL('ALTER TABLE Customer MODIFY Address char(100);'),
```

PS: Since you have only 50 entries here, you can just follow Daniel's comment. However when dealing with a large number of rows, I would recommend the migration method.

Hope it helps!